# Inconsistent behavior when joining strings with pipes

Tags: sql, postgresql

This snippet is a part in a function takes an integer(and ID) and a string (a table name) as indata, referred to as $1 and $2. In the first example, as the function currently works, the input will be `(68, 'heat_arcs')` and the function works. However, the function needs to be expanded to work with different tables, so I figured I could change `cost FROM heat_arcs'` to `cost FROM ' || $2 ||'`, but that produces a syntax error, due to "unterminated quoted string".

Why can I successfully join the string with the input data in the later part of the query, but not the early part? pgr_trsp asks for strings as input for both the first and the last parameter

Current:

```
FROM pgr_trsp(
                'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM heat_arcs',
                r, 2, false, false, 'select 1000 as to_cost, b.target_id, a.via_path::text from 
    (select gid as target_id from '|| $2 ||' where source = ' || $1 ||' or target = ' || $1 ||' ) as b,
    (select gid as via_path from '|| $2 ||' where source = ' || $1 ||' or target ='|| $1 ||' ) as a WHERE b.target_id <> a.via_path'
```

Desired:

```
FROM pgr_trsp(
                'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM '|| $2 ||',
                r, 2, false, false, 'select 1000 as to_cost, b.target_id, a.via_path::text from 
    (select gid as target_id from '|| $2 ||' where source = ' || $1 ||' or target = ' || $1 ||' ) as b,
    (select gid as via_path from '|| $2 ||' where source = ' || $1 ||' or target ='|| $1 ||' ) as a WHERE b.target_id <> a.via_path'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself on this one: you have a stray quote mark! The syntax highlighting in your question (and in your editor) gives it away if you look closely.

In the working version we have a string, a comma, and a literal `r`:

```
'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM heat_arcs', r
```

In the broken version, we have a string which *contains* the comma and the r:

```
 'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM '|| $2 ||', r
```

Taking out the concatenation, that's:

```
 'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM heat_arcs, r
```

So what you actually wanted was:

```
 'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM '|| $2, r
```

Note that since you're creating dynamic SQL, you should really make sure to use the correct [quoting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) (as well as sanity-checking the argument against a whitelist, ideally):

```
 'SELECT gid as id,  source, target, cost FROM '|| quote_ident($2), r
```

Comment: Much appreciated, IMSoP. I'll also take your advice and check out quoting functions :)